# Using ConfigureAwait in nested async methods

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor

I'm developing Blazor Server web application, and I'm torn on using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. I know that I shouldn't use it in component code, but I'm not sure about nested code. For example: I'm calling async method to update data on page on button click. This method itself also calls async method to make request to the API. Question is - should this nested method (API request) be called with `ConfigureAwait(false)` or not?

**Edit:** Adding Code to demonstrate more clearly:

This method is called from button `OnClick`

```
protected async Task GridRefresh()
{
    Models = null;
    _errorMessage = null;
    try
    {
        Models = await _dataService.GetDataAsync(Active);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _errorMessage = ex.Message.Split("Message:").Last();
    }
}
```

This method is located in `DataService` class that I add to my component using Dependency Injection

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>> GetDataAsync(int id)
{
    var container = await ApiWrapper.getByIDAsync(id);
    if(container == null)
        throw new Exception($"Container with code {id} not found!");

    return container.Items;
}
```

Question is: should I use `ConfigureAwait` in `GetDataAsync` method?

```
var container = await ApiWrapper.getByIDAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: It depends on what you do after the `await`. Can you show an example of your code?

Comment: What do you mean by `nested`? The guidance isn't for *components*, it's about libraries or "other" code in general, to allow the top-level code to decide whether to return to the original sync code, eg the UI thread. Libraries *should* use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. That goes for your own non-UI code. The UI code *should not*, because it *does* need to return to the original context to update the UI

Comment: Please,Show your code......

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I added code to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review the `GetDataAsync` method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>> GetDataAsync(int id)
{
    var container = await ApiWrapper.getByIDAsync(id);
    if(container == null)
        throw new Exception($"Container with code {id} not found!");

    return container.Items;
}
```

After the awaiting of the `getByIDAsync`, two lines of code will be executed:

```
if(container == null)
    throw new Exception($"Container with code {id} not found!");

return container.Items;
```

Currently these two lines will be executed on the Blazor's synchronization context. Is it required? It depends on the code running in the accessor of the `Items` property of the `container` object. Is there any code that interacts with any UI component? If yes, or if you are not sure, then you shouldn't add `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the awaiting of the `getByIDAsync`. If no (which is the most probable), then using `ConfigureAwait(false)` will have no negative repercussions. The positive aspects of adding the `ConfigureAwait(false)` is that will allow the caller to [block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) without deadlocking your application:

```
Models = _dataService.GetDataAsync(Active).Result; // Bad practice
```

Adding the `ConfigureAwait(false)` will also make your code slightly more efficient. And by slightly I mean practically negligible. So don't base your decision on this, but on what the code does, and on how it is intended to be used.

Answer (score 3):

You should do the same thing you'd do in desktop applications.

- To update the UI, you *must* to be on its synchronization context, so you **should not** use `ConfigureAwait(false)` when updating the UI.
- In non-UI code there's no need to get back to the UI context, so you should *probably* use `ConfigureAwait(false)` and let the top-level code decide whether it needs to get back to the UI context. This way you avoid possible deadlocks if the UI thread/context is busy.
- In library code you *should* use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid forcing a context switch and possibly a deadlock

In small, clean components (the kind of components you should be building anyway) there shouldn't be such a big problem if you omit `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

In library code, omitting `ConfigureAwait(false)` can *easily* lead to deadlocks, especially during debugging. In fact, I wonder if the deadlocks experienced by some popular local storage package is caused by some missed `ConfigureAwait` calls

Answer (score 1):

The same rules apply to any UI framework.

`ConfigureAwait(false)`, affords a very small efficiency. However, you would generally keep it out of top level UI code.

To answer the question directly:

> This method is located in DataService class that I add to my component
> using Dependency Injection. should I use ConfigureAwait in
> GetDataAsync method?

In this scenario, it's fine.

**The long story**

[Synchronization context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#synchronization-context)

> Blazor uses a synchronization context (SynchronizationContext) to
> enforce a single logical thread of execution. A component's lifecycle
> methods and any event callbacks that are raised by Blazor are executed
> on the synchronization context.
>
> Blazor Server's synchronization context attempts to emulate a
> single-threaded environment so that it closely matches the WebAssembly
> model in the browser, which is single threaded. At any given point in
> time, work is performed on exactly one thread, giving the impression
> of a single logical thread. No two operations execute concurrently.

In short, it runs on a single UI thread and with its own synchronization context, so don't call `ConfigureAwait(false)` in top level code, just use the same logic as you do on any other UI framework that has as synchronization context for a message pump or dispatcher.

Which seems to be backed up by [SteveSandersonMS](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS) in this github question [Blazor Question: ConfigureAwait(false) in Server-Side Blazor?](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19004)

> Yes, Blazor Server is a UI framework which requires your code to run
> on its sync context. Therefore do not use ConfigureAwait(false) within
> your Blazor component code.

and also from [mkArtakMSFT](https://github.com/mkArtakMSFT) in this github question [Guidance on using ConfigureAwait(...) in async life-cycle methods in Razor component](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13545)

> Our guidance is to simply not use ConfigureAwait in Blazor.
>
> ...
>
> Just for UI related scenarios. For non-UI impacting scenarios (query a
> data store or a service) `ConfigureAwait(false)` is useful.

Comment: The question asks about *other* code - code that doesn't update the UI directly

Comment: @TheGeneral I added code to edit, to more accurately get across what I'm asking